# each block create a Nil class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want calculate components of an average

**Controller**

```
  def set_average_course
    @course = @group.courses.find(params[:course_id])
    @evaluations = @course.evaluations
    @evaluations.each do |evaluation|
      @numerator += evaluation.average * evaluation.coefficient
      @denumerator += evaluation.coefficient 
    end
    @average = @numerator / @denumerator
    @course.update(average: average)
  end
```

**Logs**

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass)
```

But

```
@numerator += evaluation.average * evaluation.coefficient
```

is well defined outside the .each block

Comment: Are you initialized `@numerator` and `@denumerator` to `0`?

Comment: if I initialize, I get: ZeroDivisionError (divided by 0)

Comment: @clement that's a different problem (with the algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

It would be better and more efficient to compute the values using SQL:

The code will look like this:

```
def set_average_course
  @course = @group.courses.find(params[:course_id])
  res = Evaluation.select("SUM(Evaluations.average * Evaluations.coefficient) AS numerator, SUM(Evaluations.coefficient) AS denumerator").
    where(course_id: @course.id)

  average = res.first['numerator'] / res.first['denominator'] # Raise an error if 0
  @course.update(average: average)
end
```

Hope this leads you to the right direction

Answer (score 0):

When you enter the `each` loop for the first time, `@numerator` and `@denumerator` are not initialized yet. Instance variables are different from local variables in that they evaluate to `nil` if not initialized yet, whereas a reference to an uninitialized local variable will thrown an error. The solution is to initialize the variables to the neutral element of addition, which is `0`, before entering the loop:

```
def set_average_course
  @course = @group.courses.find(params[:course_id])
  @evaluations = @course.evaluations
  @numerator = 0
  @denumerator = 0
  @evaluations.each do |evaluation|
    @numerator += evaluation.average * evaluation.coefficient
    @denumerator += evaluation.coefficient 
  end
  @average = @numerator / @denumerator
  @course.update(average: average)
end
```

Although, as a side note, I think you mean "denominator" instead of "denumerator". You will also have to account for the case where `@denumerator` is equal to `0`, for example, when `@evaluations` is empty:

```
def set_average_course
  @course = @group.courses.find(params[:course_id])
  @evaluations = @course.evaluations
  return if @evaluations.blank?                       # or raise an error
  @numerator = 0
  @denumerator = 0
  @evaluations.each do |evaluation|
    @numerator += evaluation.average * evaluation.coefficient
    @denumerator += evaluation.coefficient 
  end
  @average = @numerator / @denumerator
  @course.update(average: average)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize `numerator` and `denumerator` to number like @p11y's answer.

My suggestion is to calculate average more ruby way like this:

```
@numerator = @evaluations.map { |e| e.average * e.coefficient }.reduce(&:+)
@denumerator = @evaluations.map { |e| e.coefficient }.reduce(&:+) 
@average = @numerator / @denumerator
```